# Refresh dynamic html table in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I have html table populated from XML. It looks like (simplified):

```
<table datascr=#xmlData>
  <tr>
    <td><span DATAFLD="ID"></span></td>
    <td><span DATAFLD="NAME"></span></td>
[...]
<tr></table>
```

I have a JavaScript function that creates a new XML with values dependent on the user's choice. The question is: how can I refresh this html table to display new values ( in javascript)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know, you don't need to refresh. 
The table will display new values as soon as the new dom objects got inserted into this table.

Comment: Well unfortunly it isnt. Maybe I miss something but simple `getElementByID('tableID').datascr = newXML;` is not working.

Comment: Try firebug to see if this line changed the DOM or the HTML.

Comment: Since you have this accepted, care to tell us what it is you did to fix the problem?